# How to specify type of binding (http or tcp) when using IChannelFactory<TChannel>? What is the default underlying binding?

Tags: c#, wcf, channelfactory

I am fairly new to WCF and am trying to understand what default underlying binding is used when we use IChannelFactory to create a channel. 
We have 2 method signatures to create channels with IChannelFactory but none of them have a parameter that take the type of binding for the channel. 
CreateChannel(EndpointAddress) and CreateChannel(EndpointAddress, Uri) are the 2 methods that I can see.

So what is the default binding used when we create a channel using the interface and if I need to change the default binding how can I do it? 
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: have you try searching in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/)

Comment: @vasily.sib Yes, with no luck. 
Maybe I am not looking at the right place. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Happens you can create a channel with just the IChannelFactory as binding would be missing. So my question doesn't make much sense. I ended up following [this](https://megakemp.com/2009/07/02/isolating-wcf-through-dependency-injection-part-ii/) article, creating a custom IClientChannelFactory and creating a channel Factory, that would return channels, within the ClientChannelFactory class.

Answer (score 1):

The `ChannelFactory<T>` constructor takes the binding as a parameter. So, you can do something like this

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress address = new 
EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8000/ChannelApp");

ChannelFactory<IRequestChannel> factory = new ChannelFactory<IRequestChannel>(binding, address);

IRequestChannel channel = factory.CreateChannel();
```

This sample was taken from the class reference at [WCF Channel Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channelfactory-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I am passing IChannelFactory<T> via DI layer which is bound to ChannelFactory<T>. So in the class where I inject the interface I do not have access to the constructor that has been mentioned above. Which is why I am trying to find out more about IChannelFactory<T> and the default binding.